# Single node Openstack installation on Ubuntu Server 14.04.2

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install Openstack on Ubuntu server 14.04.2 on a single machine (Intel PowerEdge 2950, 32 GB RAM, 3 hard drives on hardware RAID)

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install juju
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/experimental
$ sudo apt-get install openstack
$ sudo  install openstack-install
```

Then I choose a password and single-node installation

Then a new screen appears. It has two steps:

```
Creating container:
Bootstrapping juju:
```

But the system never completes 'Creating container' step (I let is it run endlessly for 1 hour)

Looking at the commands.log file, it seems that it gets hung on:

```
"Attempting to reset the terminal"
```

I would greatly appreciate help from anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your ~/.cloud-install/commands.log?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done the juju path. I've attempted many installers. The only way I've been able to do it reliably is with Openstack Fuel. Using virt-manger, create one vm for Fuel. Install Fuel in to the VM. Two more vm, one for controller, and one for compute. Configure these two VM to DHCP boot from the fuel server. Use the Fuel web interface to configure an Fuel Environment. That's the Fuel way having multiple groups of hosts run an instance of Openstack. There is a detailed description on how to setup linux bridges to use all fuel defaults.

The enclosed post says use Ubuntu 16.04. The same procedure also works on Ubuntu 14.04

http://www.jeffreygong.com/2016/07/deploying-openstack-with-fuel-on-kvm.html